# Search dropdown doesn't use z-index correctly

Tags: magento-2.1

We have a search dropdown on our website. But when you search it generates a dropdown that doesn't function correctly. When searching the dropdown has the wrong z-index, so when clicking the searched keyword it redirects to the category underneath:

[image: Underneath is the cat]

The website can be found here: https://www.thefixedgearshop.com/

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it's a z-index issue in your style sheet https://www.thefixedgearshop.com/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/nl_NL/css/styles-l.css, line 2736:

```
.block-search {
    z-index: 4; /* raise this to 6 */
}
```

You'd be better off posting CSS-related issues to stackoverflow rather than Magento stackexchange.